# Is storage in fog similar to the cloud? Does the fog node do some processing on the data before sending to the cloud?

Tags: cloud, fog

Does the fog node do the processing before sending the data to cloud for storage? If so what kind of processing is been done?

Answer (score 0):

Fog is a wrapper to various cloud APIs. For storage, it helps make it easier to use the various cloud providers. It does not do additional processing, it just sends along whatever you give it. So if processing needs to be done, you would need to take care of that first outside of fog. Hope that helps.